# UNIX, get environment variable

Tags: unix, shell, environment, echo

I have a ridiculous question due to a ridiculous problem.

Normally if I want to get the contents of an environment variable in a UNIX shell, I can do

```
echo ${VAR}
```

Let's assume, due to my ridiculous situation, that this isn't possible.

How do I get the contents of an environment variable to stdout, without someone who is looking at the command itself (not the output), see the value of the environment variable?

I can picture the solution being something like `echo env(NAME_OF_VAR)` although I can't seem to find it. The solution has to work in sh.

**PS** I can't write a script for this, it must be a built-in Unix command (I know, ridiculous problem).

Comment: Mike, are you ok? Are you being held with a gun to your head by the mafia in some warehouse? Is this a plea for help?

Comment: What's the problem ? A keyboard where '{' is invisible / inaccessible ?

Comment: @Tim .. my situation was almost that bad. But now, I'm OK

Comment: short answer, emergency bug fix at work. the practices at this place are terrible (understatement of the year). the purpose was to ensure a user wasn't seeing a password that was supposed to be hidden. the previous developer had set up the design so that it passed a plain-text password through stdin to the application. i get sick just thinking of it. anyway, i was able to use skwllsps suggestion. a horrible fix to a horrible problem resulting in a horrible company making horrible software.

Comment: Another situation where this is useful: on Windows, environment variables may contain parentheses, and you cannot do *e.g.* `echo ${ProgramFiles(x86)}` because the shell will try to attempt a subsitution. However `printenv 'ProgramFiles(x86)'` works.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can do:

```bash
printenv VARIABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Ooh, something out of /usr/ucb.  Impressive.

Answer (score 13):

type the following command in terminal, it will display all the list of environment variables

**printenv**

now print the wanted variable like this:

**echo $VARIABLENAME**

Answer (score 9):

Using `${!VAR_NAME}` should be what you are looking for

```
> FOO=BAR123
> VAR_NAME=FOO
> echo ${VAR_NAME}
FOO
> echo ${!VAR_NAME}
BAR123
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
myVariable=$(env  | grep VARIABLE_NAME | grep -oe '[^=]*$');
```

Comment: actually you're probably better off using cut at the end e.g. ... | cut -d '=' -f2-

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this:

```
ENV() {
    printf 'echo $%s\n' $1 | sh
}
```

This works in plain old Bourne shell.

Comment: I'd use more quoting myself:  `ENV() { printf 'printf "%%s\\n" "${%s}"\n' "$1" | sh; }`

Answer (score 3):

The solution really depends on what the restrictions are why you can't use a simple `$VAR`. Maybe you could call a shell that doesn't have the restrictions and let this sub-shell evaluate the variable:

```
bash -c 'echo $VAR'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | grep $var
```

search for all unix-compatible format variables been used

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer

Comment: Always remember to add explaination to the answer you post, so the users can understand the use of it.  @user3061097