# Rails 6 is unable to connect to AWS Elastic Beanstalk provisioned RDS. Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am having a very difficult time trying to launch a sample Rails 6 application to Elastic Beanstalk. For context, I am following these instructions

[ADD RDS to Ruby Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.rds.html)

[ADD an RDS to Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html)

I have followed these instructions to a tee and am still unable to connect to the rds database that I have provisioned. I keep receiving the following error:

> PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Whenever I try to run `RAILS_ENV=production rails db:migrate` or any other rake task, I keep getting that error.

On my AWS console, under **Configuration** and **Software**, I have the following environment variables:

[image]

Also in my `database.yml` file I have the rds configured variables listed as such.

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

I have mapped my values as instructed in the documentation and am certain that they are correct.

Finally, I have sshed into my beanstalk provisioned ec2 instance and have executed the following command:

```
psql -U username -p 5432 -h examplehost.rds.amazonaws.com -d ebdb
```

provided the password and am able to connect. I am really at my wits end, I've spent too much time trying to diagnose this and am running out of ideas. I don't know where to look too next for ideas on how to trouble shoot this. I've read so many stack overflow questions and blogs that my head is spinning. If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

---Update----
I have created a new environment variable on the elastic beanstalk console.

```
ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourHostname:5432/YourDatabaseName
```

I made the necessary configurations, uploaded my .zip file and the connection to the database failed.

---- UPDATE-----

`printenv` does not show the varialbes provided by beanstalk, however this command does `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment`.

Comment: Can you start the rails console from within your app? `cd /var/app/current` and then start the console?

Comment: Is the rails server and rack env set to production mode?

Comment: Thank you guys for responding. Yes both variables are set to production and I am able to access the rails console. However if I try to make any kind of query or active record statement I recieve `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`. I was able to make it work temporarily by just hard coding the production values on my deployed rails app in `database.yml`. This makes me think that the app cannot read the RDS environment variables somehow despite placing them in the console..

Comment: Oh good detective work, but weird that the environment variables aren't getting picked up. In the console, can you double check to see if they are getting set?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that at this point. From what I can tell, it is picking up all the other variables. So what I'm going to try tomorrow is create a new env variable called `DATABASE_URL` and have it set to this postgresql connection string. `postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourHostname:5432/YourDatabaseName`. I'll configure my `database.yml` to use it and then I'll see if that did the trick.

Comment: Let us know how it goes. In the console you can just enter `ENV["RDS_DB_NAME"]` at the prompt and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: It turns out that none of the variables are being read. Only `nil` is being outputted. It looks like for the time being I'll have to just hardcode the rds ENV variables, which is annoying.

Comment: Huh, that's not great for security. It looks like you've set everything up correctly as far as you've noted here. It might be worth it to pay for AWS support and see if they have any ideas. They can't help you with your code, but maybe they can identify something else that isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My first advice is that, in my opinion, it is a much better option to create an Amazon RDS on their own, and not tied to Beanstalk.

As the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html) indicates (emphasis mine):

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk provides support for running Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) instances in your Elastic Beanstalk environment. To learn about that, see Adding a database to your Elastic Beanstalk environment. **This works great for development and testing environments. However, it isn't ideal for a production environment because it ties the lifecycle of the database instance to the lifecycle of your application's environment.**

And:

> To decouple your database instance from your environment, you can run a database instance in Amazon RDS and configure your application to connect to it on launch. This enables you to connect multiple environments to a database, terminate an environment without affecting the database, and perform seamless updates with blue-green deployments.

In my opinion, even for testing or development, it is always advisable to configure a small database instance and give your application the ability of define the most appropriate mechanism for connecting to your database.

The only *downside* is that you will probably need to configure a [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/rds-external-defaultvpc.html), although it should not be actually a problem and, in ay case, it is worth value.

If for any reason you need to use the Beanstalk provisioned RDS database perhaps you have some workarounds to your problem (it should be a workaround because your configuration looks fine - please, only, verify that the database configuration is defined for the right Beanstalk environment).

For instance, one thing you can try is to store the database connection configuration in a S3 bucket, as also suggested in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/rds-external-credentials.html). The idea is basically create some configuration file with the necessary connectivity information, store it in S3, and read that configuration in your application, i.e., process that file, in order to initialize your database.

But maybe you can try another approach.

Please, consider this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562714/elastic-beanstalk-custom-ami-cant-see-environment-variables), and the answer from Jon McAuliffe and others. As indicated, Beanstalk will provide your application with environment variables, but maybe this variables will not be exposed as shell variables, they will be exposed to your application in different ways depending on the runtime the application needs to be executed on.

In the case of Ruby, you are accessing these variables in the [correct way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) but, for any reason, your program is not having access to that information.

This probably also explains why `printenv` does not print any if your variables but the [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html) script does.

But maybe you can take advantage of the fact that `get-config` provides you the right information and, either define this variables in your `ENV` by executing the `get-config` script for every `RDS*` key, perhaps in your `environment.rb` - please, be aware that I programmed in Ruby when I was a student but there is a long time since that, do the task in the file you consider appropriate - or using [`.ebextensions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-during.html) and a custom configuration file. You can find several examples [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/9720e38e9da155752dce132a31d8e13a27364b83/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/timezone-linux.config).

For instance, consider the following (copy and paste, with minor modifications of [this example configuration](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/9720e38e9da155752dce132a31d8e13a27364b83/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/rds-ssl-java.config)):

```
commands:
  01_update_env:
    command: "/tmp/update_environment_variables.sh"

files:
  "/tmp/update_environment_variables.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      content : |
        #!/bin/bash

        RDS_HOSTNAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_HOSTNAME)
        if [ -z "$RDS_HOSTNAME" ]; then
                echo "Could not determine RDS hostname"
                exit 1
        fi
        echo "RDS hostname $RDS_HOSTNAME..."
        # Just export the variable at OS level, or make it visible to
        # the rails env in some other way
        export RDS_HOSTNAME=$RDS_HOSTNAME

        # Process the rest of the variables...
        # Probably we should create a list and iterate through it
```

A similar approach could be the one exposed in [this stackoverrun question](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/8088203), but restricted to the container that Beanstalk will use to encapsulate your app. AFAIK, the container should receive as `env` variables the different `RDS*` ones corresponding to the database configuration.

Dan, be aware that I have not tested these solutions, they are only ideas: please, be careful with that, I do not want to cause any damage to your system.

Comment: @DanRubio, were you able to try any of the proposed solutions?

Comment: Hey @jccampanero thanks for your reply, I gave you the bounty but the suggestions did not work after all. I have a decoupled rds database and have abandoned beanstalk entirely to simply move to a provisioned ec2 instance with the packages installed. I've found that beanstalk has too many problems with various steps in deployments and setup. It was simpler to just setup the ec2 instance itself at this point instead of bulldozing through. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi @DanRubio. Thank you very much, I really appreciate that you gave me the bounty. I am sorry that none of the provided suggestions worked. I think you made a good decision to have the database separately. An ec2 instance provisioned with the correct packages is fine too. In any case, please, consider also other options like deploying your application in containers, directly or with Kubernetes. Thank you again Dan: please, if you think that I can be of any help, do not hesitate to contact me, I will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this problem with a mysql server that might still help you. Basically, even though I followed all your steps, could see my envars using `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` and could connect directly to my database with the `mysql` command, I was still getting the following error:
`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError)`

The solution turned out to be the fact that Elastic Beanstalk was not connecting my envars to my `bundle exec rails console` command in the `eb ssh` instance access. I solved the issue by prepending all of the required envars explicitly to any rails commands I ran from within the `eb ssh` instance access. So for example, in order to run `rails console`, I had to run the following:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=xxxxxxx RAILS_ENV=production RDS_HOSTNAME=xxxxxxx RDS_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx RDS_USERNAME=xxxxxxx RDS_DB_NAME=xxxxxxx AWS_REGION=xxxxxxx AWS_BUCKET=xxxxxxx bundle exec rails c
```

Replace the `xxxxxxx`s above with the values from the corresponding variables in your EB > Configuration > Software tab, and you should be able to connect to the remote database and run migrations, rake tasks and other database-reliant functions.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux2 instances I was having the same issue and just noticed that the env variables I set in the config just didn't exist for `su` that I had set myself to -- if I remain the default login after `eb ssh` `env` prints everything I expected

edit: sorry -- `env` printing of variables on linux 2 instance enabled by
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

so what I did was find where those env variables were being exported for default user shell, which was `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` as noted in the above aws knowledge center link and just `source` that file when I needed to start the rails console as `su`